# GAE: Why is my css not found?

Tags: css, google-app-engine, yaml

With this configuration I get a HTTP 500 error.

```
application: xxx
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /style
  static_dir: style


- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /admin/.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin


- url: .*
  script: main.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

My log says this though:

```
INFO     2013-04-16 12:11:28,356 server.py:561] default: "GET /style/pimp_soef.css   HTTP/1.1" 500 2168
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style/pimp_soef.css" />
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

What about my `mainHandler`? Something to do with that!?

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: used to this <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="
style/pimp_soef.css" />   remove /

Comment: No, that's not it. Have a look [here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html)

Comment: Is it working locally?

Comment: No, not working locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the URL to the css file directly into the URL bar, that'll let you be sure the problem is not with your HTML.

Your code looks correct.

My guess is that it's something else.  A typo in the filename.  Maybe you have a capital letter.  Or your directory structure is not set up so that /style can be found.  Maybe file permissions.

Comment: I know, I checked all this myself already. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: put some logging code in your main handler just in case.  you shouldn't hit it.  Since the /style handler is listed first, that should get hit first and it'll never run your main handler.  Anyways, try hitting the URL directly with your browser, and try it with other files in your /style folder, hopefully you'll figure out something.